# Linking tables together

Tags: php, mysql

Some premise: a grower grows produce, a produce can have many varieties, but some varieties are only grown by certain growers

As such, I have 4 tables:

Produce (id, produce_name)
Varieties (id, variety_name)
Growers (id, grower_name)
Grower_variety (id, grower_id, variety_id)

I'm getting my grower_id from the session that's currently logged in.

I need to display only the varieties that the grower grows in my dropdown list.

My code so far is:

```
            <SELECT name="productcode">

            <?php

            $query   = "SELECT grower_id, variety_id FROM grower_variety WHERE grower_id = '$grower_id'"; 

            $result  = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error()); 
            while ($row     = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 

            $variety_id   = $row['variety_id']; 

            echo ?>

            <option value="<?php $variety_id;?>">
            <?php echo $variety_id;?>
            </option>

            <?php
            ; }
            ?>

            </SELECT>
```

And then I'm kind of stuck and can't get my head around it. This displays the id's of the varieties fine. But I want to end up with:

PRODUCE_NAME - VARIETY_NAME
PRODUCE_NAME - VARIETY_NAME
PRODUCE_NAME - VARIETY_NAME

in my dropdown.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: How are the varieties linked to the product? There should probably be a "ref_product" column in your "varieties" table that refers to the product ID (or such a column in your grower_variety table, but that is less normalized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1st: add a reference to the variety in the product definition. Try to fill in the x and y fields to then build your relation: "A product belongs to x to y varieties."

if y > 1, you will have to create a table to link the concepts the same way you did to link the grower and the variety, otherwise a simple foreign key will be necessary.

- 2nd: in your select, add one or 2 joins depending whether the relation is represented under a FK or a TABLE, according to your requirements.